# Filebeat output.logstash connection problem

Tags: java, filebeat, elk

I would like to collect logs from Host B using Filebeat and output them to Host A. Currently, there are no errors in the log messages. Host B is always attempting to connect to the IP address of Host A. Port on Host A has been opened, but no data is being received. When testing Filebeat locally and transmitting it to Logstash, there are no issues. Here is my configuration:

filebeat.yml

```
output.logstash:
hosts: ["XX.XX.XX.XX:5044"]
```

logstash-sample.conf

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
host => XX.XX.XX.XX
}
}
```

The firewall on Host A has been turned off. Are there any other settings that need to be configured? I appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

This is my first time asking a question here. I apologize in advance if there are any unclear explanations.

I have tried searching for information online and encountered the same issue when connecting within the same network. I even tested it using different operating systems.